# What is spin state of two bound spin half particles and two independent spin half particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This question arises from my study about bound state and unbound state to construct wave function. So I put the spin half particle to ask.

For the bound state, I understand that we can measure the total spin of the bound state. Such that the spin state of two bound spin half particle should be eigenstate of $$S=S^{(1)}+S^{(2)}.$$
So the spin state should be $\mid1,1\rangle,\mid1,0\rangle,\mid1,-1\rangle$ for the triplet state and $\mid0,0\rangle$ for singlet state.

As for two independent spin half particles spin state, I don't know. I guess that it should $\mid+,+\rangle$ or $\mid+,-\rangle$, something like these. If yes, why the they were written like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first remember that spin is a vector quantity. There isn't just one operator of spin, but three: $\hat S_x$, $\hat S_y$, $\hat S_z$. They are just non-commuting operators, so it's impossible to measure all three simultaneously (except for a case when $s=0$). They all however commute with the operator 
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 = \hat S_x^2 + \hat S_y^2 + \hat S_z^2$$
which can also be written as $$\hat {\bf S}^2 = \hat S_z (\hat S_z +1) + \hat S_-\hat S_+ $$
where $$\hat S_\pm = \hat S_x \pm {\rm i}\hat S_y$$
The spin state of the particle can be characterized by two numbers $s$ and $m_s$ 
$$ \hat{\bf S}^2|s, m_s\rangle = s(s+1)|s,m_s\rangle$$
$$ \hat S_z|s, m_s\rangle = m_s|s,m_s\rangle$$ 
It can be showed that operators $\hat S_\pm$ transit between the sates. The exact formula is:
$$ \hat S_+|s, m_s\rangle = \sqrt{s(s+1)-m_s(m_s+1)}|s, m_s+1\rangle $$
$$ \hat S_-|s, m_s\rangle = \sqrt{s(s+1)-m_s(m_s-1)}|s, m_s-1\rangle $$
The operator $\hat {\bf S}^2$, with the eigenvalue $s(s+1)\hbar^2$, is what really determines the total spin of a particle $s$. From which you can calculate $s$. The $m_s$, the eigenvalue of $\hat S_z$ can take values between $-s$ to $s$ and it is no clear indicator of the total spin of the particle. For example it is possible for a particle of spin 1 to be in an eigenstate of $S_z$ with eigenvalue $0$ or $-1$, but it doesn't mean that it has spin $0$ or $-1$.

So when you're try to detemine the total spin of a bound state you need to find the eigenstates of the operator 
$$ \hat{\bf S}^2 = (\hat S^{(1)}_x+\hat S^{(2)}_x)^2 + (\hat S^{(1)}_y+\hat S^{(2)}_y)^2 +(\hat S^{(1)}_z+\hat S^{(2)}_z)^2$$

Since the state of one particle can be expressed in the basis of states $|s,m_s\rangle$, the state of two paritcles can be expressed in the basis:
$$|s_1,m_{s1}\rangle\otimes|s_2, m_{s2}\rangle $$
Since $s_1$ and $s_2$ for fundamental particles are always constant, and are usually known, they are usually skipped to shorten the notation, let's introduce the notation
$$ |m_{s1}; m_{s2}\rangle = |s_1,m_{s1}\rangle\otimes|s_2, m_{s2}\rangle$$
For example, for two particles of spin $\frac12$, we have four base states:
$$|\frac12;\frac12\rangle, \qquad |\frac12;-\frac12\rangle, \qquad |-\frac12;\frac12\rangle, \qquad |-\frac12;-\frac12\rangle$$
which can also be denoted as
$$|+;+\rangle, \qquad |+;-\rangle, \qquad |-;+\rangle, \qquad |-;-\rangle$$
The are all eigenstates of $\hat S_{z}^{(1)}$ and $\hat S_{z}^{(2)}$:
$$\hat S_{z}^{(1)} |m_{s1};m_{s2}\rangle = m_{s1}|m_{s1};m_{s2}\rangle$$
$$\hat S_{z}^{(2)} |m_{s1};m_{s2}\rangle = m_{s2}|m_{s1};m_{s2}\rangle$$
and as a consequence, they are also eigenstates of $\hat S_z = \hat S_{z}^{(1)} + \hat S_{z}^{(2)}$:
$$(\hat S_{z}^{(1)} + \hat S_{z}^{(2)}) |m_{s1};m_{s2}\rangle = (m_{s1} + m_{s2})|m_{s1};m_{s2}\rangle$$
However, they are not all eigenstates of operator $\hat{\bf S}^2$. If we write, as before, that
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 = \hat S_z (\hat S_z +1) + \hat S_-\hat S_+ $$
where $\hat S_\pm = \hat S_\pm^{(1)} +\hat S_\pm^{(2)}$, we can find that
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 |+;+\rangle = 2|+;+\rangle$$
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 |+;-\rangle = |+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle $$
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 |-;+\rangle = |+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle $$
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 |-;-\rangle = 2|-;-\rangle$$
We can see that $|+;-\rangle$ and $|-;+\rangle$ are not eigenstates of $\hat {\bf S}^2$. Looking for actual eigenstates, we find that
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 (|+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle) = 2(|+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle) $$
$$ \hat {\bf S}^2 (|-;+\rangle - |+;-\rangle) = 0 $$
We should also add a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ to normalize them. To sum up, we have
\begin{align} &\hat {\bf S}^2 |+;+\rangle &=& 2|+;+\rangle  \\
&\hat {\bf S}^2 \frac{|+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} &=& 2\frac{|+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \\
&\hat {\bf S}^2 |-;-\rangle &=& 2|-;-\rangle\\
&\hat {\bf S}^2 \frac{|+;-\rangle - |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} &=& 0 \\
&\hat S_{z} |+;+\rangle &=& |+;+\rangle \\
&\hat S_{z} \frac{|+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} &=& 0 \\
&\hat S_{z} |-;-\rangle &=& -|-;-\rangle \\
&\hat S_{z} \frac{|+;-\rangle - |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} &=& 0 \end{align}
comparing it with the formulas
$$ \hat{\bf S}^2|s, m_s\rangle = s(s+1)|s,m_s\rangle$$
$$ \hat S_z|s, m_s\rangle = m_s|s,m_s\rangle$$ 
we can identify
$$ |+;+\rangle = |1,1\rangle $$
$$ \frac{|+;-\rangle + |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = |1,0\rangle $$
$$ |-;-\rangle = |1,-1\rangle $$
$$ \frac{|+;-\rangle - |-;+\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = |0,0\rangle $$
where on the right side the states were written in terms of their total spin and total z-component of the spin.